# What are memory stick tests actually doing?

Tags: memory

How do memory tests work in general?

Some tests must be run during pc boot, some can be run at any time after os is ready.

Theres a diagnoatic tool within Windows os, then theres another diagnoatic tool provided by your motherboard manufacturer, and i have seen some on github  distributed as opensource.

How do diagnostic tools detect problems? Which test one should one use?

If i assume that one of my memory stick Is faulty should i run multiple tests various vendors or is it a waste of time?

Answer (score 3):

They write the memory full of predefined pattern, then read it back. If they find something unexpected, they know it changed unintentionally.

Some fault modes can be determined immediately, as the unexpected result is immediately obvious. In some cases the problem only manifests after a long time. In those cases the memory is once again written full of test pattern, then the testing software waits for hours or days and then re-reads it.

Out of the free to use privately tools, Memtest86 has always done the trick for me, but the one that comes with Windows' installer does its job in a pinch. The OS installer memory tests typically have less tests than dedicate memory test software, like the Memtest86.